# Why can a batter hit a pitched ball farther than one thrown by himself?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, collision, projectile, biology

The main problem I am having is what Actually remains constant in the two cases. Is it the average force, or the time period for which the force is exerted? any helpful hints would be appreciated.

**Note** : This is not a homework question; I was asked this by a friend and am trying to intuitively figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A greatly simplified ans comes from the fact that coefficient of restitution(e) is smame for both cases ( since same bodies are colliding).

[image]

Velocity of separation =e×velocity of approach

When he throws the ball himself it is usually at very low speeds(ie a low velocity of approach)  compared to a baller who put his all in throwing the ball.

Velocity separation gives an idea of velocity of ball  . Range depends on angle of projection

Answer (score 2):

I can't really speak about physiological differences that might influence the exerted forces. But the main differences as far as the ball is concerned are:

1. Batting is an elastic impact, while throwing can be thought of as an inelastic "impact".
2. The impact speed is larger when batting

When throwing a ball, you get it to exactly the same velocity as your hand and then release it. You're grabbing it, giving it no chance to bounce away. When at full speed, you release it. That's like an inelastic impact: the two objects impacting are accelerated until their velocities are equal, either because they are sticky, or one grabs the other, or whatever reason that doesn't allow them to be separated. If one of the two objects then releases the other, the other object will continue to move with that same velocity. So if your arm has speed $v$ when releasing, then the ball will move with that speed.

When batting a ball, you first get the bat to full speed (which is higher than that of your arm, because the circular arc has a larger radius due to the bat's added length), and then the ball and bat impact elastically, where the bat can be thought of as having much higher mass than the ball, because your swinging arm gives it additional mass as well (this is probably not entirely accurate, but it's easier to handle in order to illustrate the different cases). As you may know, in the case of elastic impact of two objects where one has much larger mass than the other, the heavier object will approximately keep its velocity, while the lighter object will keep its *speed* relative to the heavier object, but reverses the direction of travel. So if the ball has speed $v_a$ and the bat has speed $v_b$, then after the impact the ball will move with speed $v_a+2v_b$. Consider that $v_b$, the bat's speed, is already higher than your arm's speed $v$ from above. And then you still add twice the ball's original speed. This should explain why batting results in way higher velocities, and thus larger distances travelled.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question. I was asking why a batter can HIT a ball pitched by a baller towards him further than one He hits after throwing it (upwards) himself

Comment: Ok, then I did misinterpret it. In that case, both cases are elastic impacts, but with different ball speeds $v_a$. In the pitched case it's non-zero, while in the thrown case it's zero. So the resulting speeds are $v_a+2v_b$ in the pitched case or just $2v_b$ in the thrown case.

Answer (score 0):

the batted ball travels faster than the pitched ball because the act of striking it with a bat adds kinetic energy to it. For a perfectly elastic ball, what remains constant is the sum of the kinetic energy of the bat and that of the ball before and after the ball is hit by the bat.

Answer (score 0):

There are a two principle factors.

The most obvious is physiological. Can the batter do as much work (force times distance) in the action of throwing as he can in swinging the bat. I don't know any clear answer to this, but I strongly suspect that the action of swinging a bat gets more body movement behind it, and therefore more work is done. Especially as a bat is heavier than a ball, and the work done is proportional to the mass accelerated.

Second, and probably more important, ignoring energy loss (inelasticity), and assuming a direct strike, the *relative* velocity between bat and ball is equal (and opposite) after collision to the relative velocity before collision. Hence the ball flies of the bat with the velocity of the bat, plus twice the velocity given the ball by the pitcher. The faster the ball is pitched, the further it can be hit.

Or think of the energy of the ball after being hit as the sum of the energy given by the batter and the pitcher.